# How can I install "DataMining Adding for Office 2007" as part of my setup?

Tags: sql-server, excel, data-mining

I'm writting a setup program that needs to install the DataMining Adding for Office 2007.

1) How do I detect if it's already installed?

2) If it is not installed, I download and run the MSI (SQLServer2008_DMAddin.msi). But how can I run the Server Configuration (Microsoft.SqlServer.DataMining.Office.ServerConfiguration.exe) tool myself and not have the addin ask questions to the user the first time they open Excel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Check if "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server DMAddins\Config" exists.

2) Use the "InstallPath" value to find and run "Microsoft.SqlServer.DataMining.Office.ServerConfiguration.exe"